# How to switch to a different view by clicking on the detailtextlabel in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a table view in which I have 3 rows. First row is to select whether the clock should be in analog or digital fashion. Second row has a toggle switch which when switched on show the weather. Third row shows the timeformat i.e whether the user wants to select time in 24 hour format  or 12 format.

The second row  has been done. But I am confused on how to do with the first one i.e by default in the detailtextlabel of the first row digital should be displayed and when i click on the cell the text should change from digital to analog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(indexPath.row == 0){
     if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Analog"]){
       cell.textLabel.text = @"Digital";
      }
     else{
       cell.textLabel.text = @"Analog";
     }
   }
}
```

Replace  cell.textLabel.text by lbl.text if you are using any another label for displaying these values.

Comment: Would you repair the indentation in this please?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the UITableView's first cell detailTextLabel, after the user clicks on it, right?

Well in the TableView delegate method, get a refference to the cell the user clicked on and modify it's detailTextLabel....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.textLabel.text = @"New Text";
}
```

Just make sure to check which cell the user clicked on before you change the text, since you have 3 cells...
Either check the cell row, or the cell existing text